# He followed me into/to my home- meaning difference

Tags: prepositions, sentence-meaning

> 1. He followed me **into** my home.
> 2. He followed me **to** my home.

What's the difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 2):

There is a "he" and there is a "me". He followed you.

> He followed me into my home.

can mean that he followed you to your home **and** he entered into your home.

> He followed me to my home.

means he followed you and your destination was your home. *But* it is not necessarily the case that he entered your home. Maybe the two of you stopped in front, and talked on the porch, or on the driveway. It is not guaranteed that he entered the home.